# how to differntiate current location and nearby location using two different markers in gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

Iam using gmaps4rails to show gmaps in my application.iam getting the map points right but iam unable to differentiate the current location and nerby locations in my map.my idea  is to use different markers for two locations i did it in the following way but it didnt worked for me

**my controller**

```
def profile

   @googlemaplocation=Location.find_by_id("#{params[:clinic_id]}")

    @json1 = @googlemaplocation.to_gmaps4rails do |locations, marker|

  marker.picture({
                  :picture => "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/dd-start.png",
                  :width   => 32,
                  :height  => 32
                 })
  end

    @neargooglemaplocation=@googlemaplocation.nearbys(10)
    @json2= @neargooglemaplocation.to_gmaps4rails do |locations, marker|

  marker.picture({
                  :picture => "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/dd-start.png",
                  :width   => 32,
                  :height  => 32
                 })
  end

    @json = (JSON.parse(@json1) + JSON.parse(@json2)).to_json

  end
```

**my view**

```
<%= gmaps(:markers => { :data => @json } ) %>
```

what should i do if i want to display two different markers on the same map

Thanks & Regards
Hari Krishna

Comment: maybe a different picture?

Answer (score 1):

As said by apneadiving, you could use different images. For example :

```
def profile

   @googlemaplocation=Location.find_by_id("#{params[:clinic_id]}")

    @json1 = @googlemaplocation.to_gmaps4rails do |locations, marker|

  marker.picture({
                  :picture => "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png",
                  :width   => 32,
                  :height  => 32
                 })
  end

    @neargooglemaplocation=@googlemaplocation.nearbys(10)
    @json2= @neargooglemaplocation.to_gmaps4rails do |locations, marker|

  marker.picture({
                  :picture => "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png",
                  :width   => 32,
                  :height  => 32
                 })
  end

    @json = (JSON.parse(@json1) + JSON.parse(@json2)).to_json

  end
```

By the way: thank you, I was looking for a way to add markers for nearby locations in my app :)

Regards.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me. I am also working on the same thing.